# Tethering android wifi connection

Tags: android, android-wifi, adhoc

I would like to create a small android application (for testing purposes) that is able to tether host android device's wifi connection (not 3G) to another android device. I've looked at a number of tethering solutions and all of them seem to only tether the 3G connection of the host phone. Due to some restrictions of the project, I cannot use the ad-hoc mode. Is there a way to do it on android 2.2 without using ad-hoc and without wifi-direct capabilities?

Comment: First you have to show, what you have done so far, than we can suggest you the exact solution which best match to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

old thread and I might be way late, but try bluetooth

Some examples of Android <-> PC, but I don't see why Android <-> Android isn't possible.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXCLslod6Xc
- http://www.androidactivity.com/
- http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2.05/group3/index.html